# How to make the browser display non-English text in a popup triggered by the beforeunload event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to show a message before a visitor leaves my page. Here is the code I am using.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    .....
    return 'my-message-in-English-or-Chinese';
}
```

My website supports both English and Chinese. The problem is that even though I provide Chinese for display, the other text generated by the browser is still in English. The following is a screenshot of what I get in Chrome (a mix of Chinese and English). I want all text to be displayed in Chinese.

[image: enter code here]

Comment: For that you need to change the locale of the browser, which is entirely in the user's place.

Comment: If the user installed a US localized version of the browser this means that he wants to receive the messages using this locale and there is not much you could do to change this.

Comment: do you want to change the message or localize buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't control  the display of the "Confirm navigation" dialog.  This dialog is browser dependent.  Some browsers don't even display the custom message.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible - the other text is based on the language of the browser which cannot be changed from the page.